# Try and catch C++

Tags: c++

I am having trouble getting the try and catch to work properly in this code. It keeps the code from getting "loopy" when a char is entered instead of a number, however, it does not give the cout<<"Invalid entry"; response I am looking for. My Professor hinted to use the try and catch method if there is a better way to catch a char where there should be an int I am open to suggestions. 
Here is the code. It is for an assignment FizzBuzz.

```
int main() {
    int choice, choiceArray;
    string userArray;

    cout << "Welcome to the FizzBuzz program!"<< endl;

    cout << "This program will check if the number you enter is divisible by 3, 5, or both." << endl;

    try {
        while(true) {       
            cout << "Enter a positive number"<< endl;
            cin >> choice;
            cout << endl;

            if (choice % 3 == 0 && choice % 5 == 0) {
                cout << "Number " << choice << " - FizzBuzz!" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else if (choice % 3 == 0) {
                cout << "Number " << choice << " Fizz!" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else if (choice % 5 == 0) {
                cout << "Number " << choice << " Buzz!" << endl;
                break;
            }           
            else {
                cout << "Number entered is not divisible by 3 or 5, please try again." << endl;
            }   
        } 
    }
    catch (...) {
        cout << "Invalid entry" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `cin` doesn't use exceptions by default, you can turn them on with `cin.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit);`  Or just check the state explicitly, like `if (cin >> choice) { /* ok */ } else { /* bad input */ }`  Either way, you have to reset the failure state (`cin.clear()`) and remove the bad data from the stream (`std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`) before trying again.

Comment: There's not much to catch there, unless you enable throwing exceptions as mentioned by @Ben!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cin` doesn't use exceptions by default, you can turn them on with

```
cin.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit);
```

Without exceptions, you can also detect bad input by checking the stream state explicitly, like

```
if (cin >> choice) { /* ok */ }
else { /* bad input */ }
```

Either way, you have to reset the failure state (`cin.clear()`) and remove the bad data from the stream (`std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`) before trying again.

Answer (score 3):

Besides what [@Ben said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43959167/1413395), it's a fairly bad idea to `catch` any exeption unspecified with

```
catch (...) {
    cout << "Invalid entry" << endl;
}
```

That should be the absolutely last resort, and you can't reliably tell that it was an exception because of an `"Invalid entry"` or any different reason.

At least you should catch a `std::exception` before instead

```
catch (const std::exception& e) {
   cout << "Exception caught: '" << e.what() << "'!" << endl;
}
catch(...)  {
   cout << "Exception caught: Unspecified reason!" << endl;
}
```

and use the `what()` function to provide more specific information.

Comment: Thank you @Ben for all your help!